# Proposed tag: polymer physics

Tags: feature-request, tags

I've posted a few questions here relating to physics of polymers in solution, and I am surprised every time that there is no dedicated tag for them. A couple of examples of my own questions: [Hindered rotation model for flexible polymers: deriving the Flory characteristic ratio](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/256207/hindered-rotation-model-for-flexible-polymers-deriving-the-flory-characteristic), and [Scaling argument for friction force on a chain in shear flow](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/305930/scaling-argument-for-friction-force-on-a-chain-in-shear-flow).

I can't seem to find a good tag to appropriately direct this sort of question on this site.

Comment: Isn't polymer physics part of [tag:condensed-matter]?

Comment: That's probably the closest one, now that you mention it, but condensed matter typically evokes bulk material properties, while polymer physics refers to individual macromolecules.

Comment: I would say the "physics" part is redundant, and it should just be "polymers.". A quick search for questions about polymers turns up approx. 90 questions that could be tagged as such (although I didn't go through the entire list, it could end up being shorter).

Comment: "polymers" would also cover it, you're right that the physics is not needed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have added the [polymers](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polymers) tag to both of your questions. It's now your job to go through the search that tpg2114 mentioned and add the tag as a suggested edit where appropriate. (However, please only do this a few at a time - no more than 2-4 a day - so as not to overwhelm the front page.)

For people reviewing those edits, please do take the due diligence to check that the tag actually applies to the question.

Comment: Will do, thank you